# image preview disappear while editing the other form value in VueJs

Tags: image, vue.js, vue-component

i am using VueJs for my frontend and i have form with text and file inputs. while uploading file i am showing image preview. image preview appears perfectly but as soon as i edit other form fields , the preview disappears. don't understand what is happening here. please help..

here i'm adding some codes,

this is the Whole code of fileupload.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
          <form role="form" @submit.prevent="saveImage">
            <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
              <label for="note">Description</label>
              <textarea
                id="desc"
                v-model="form.desc"
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('desc') }"
                name="desc"
              ></textarea>
              <has-error :form="form" field="desc" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xl-3">
              <label for="input1">Input 1</label>
              <input
                id="input1"
                v-model="form.input1"
                type="number"
                class="form-control"
                :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('input1') }"
                name="input1"
              />
              <has-error :form="form" field="input1" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-xl-3">
              <label for="input2">Input 2</label>
              <input
                id="input2"
                v-model="form.input2"
                type="number"
                class="form-control"
                :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('input2') }"
                name="input2"
              />
              <has-error :form="form" field="input2" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xl-4">
              <label for="image">Main Image</label>
              <div class="custom-file">
                <input
                  id="image"
                  type="file"
                  class="custom-file-input"
                  name="image"
                  :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('image') }"
                  @change="onFileChange"
                />
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="image">{{$t('common.choose_file')}}</label>
              </div>
              <has-error :form="form" field="image" />
              <div class="bg-light mt-4 w-25">
                <img
                  v-if="url"
                  :src="url"
                  class="img-fluid"
                  :alt="$t('common.image_alt')"
                />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xl-4">
              <div class="custom-file">
                <input
                  multiple="true"
                  id="all_image"
                  ref="files"
                  type="file"
                  class="custom-file-input"
                  name="all_image"
                  :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('all_image') }"
                  @change="onFileMultipleChange"
                />
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="all_image">{{
                  $t('common.choose_file')
                }}</label>
              </div>
              <has-error :form="form" field="all_image" />
              <div class="bg-light mt-4 w-50 row" style="width: 100% !important;">
                <div class="file-listing col-md-6"  v-for="(file, key) in files" :key="key">
                  <img :src="file.image" v-bind:ref="'image'+parseInt( key )" style="height: 150px;width: 150px;"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <v-button :loading="form.busy" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="fas fa-save" /> {{ $t('common.save') }}
          </v-button>
          <button
            type="reset"
            class="btn btn-secondary float-right"
            @click="resetform()">
            <i class="fas fa-power-off" /> {{ $t('common.reset') }}
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
 import Form from 'vform'
 export default {
  middleware: ['auth', 'check-permissions'],
data: () => ({
form: new Form({
  image: '',
  all_image:[],
  desc:'',
  input1:'',
  input2:''

}),
url: null,
files:[],
  }),
 methods: {
onFileChange(e) {
  const file = e.target.files[0]
  const reader = new FileReader()
  if (
    file.size < 2111775 &&
    (file.type === 'image/jpeg' ||
      file.type === 'image/png' ||
      file.type === 'image/gif')
  ) {
    reader.onloadend = (file) => {
      this.form.image = reader.result
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    this.url = URL.createObjectURL(file)
  } else {
    Swal.fire(
      this.$t('common.error'),
      this.$t('common.image_error'),
      'error'
    )
  }
},

getImagePreviews(){
  for( let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++ ){
    if ( /\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|mov|mp4|mkv)$/i.test( this.files[i].name ) ) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      let iname = /\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$/i.test( this.files[i].name );
      reader.addEventListener("load", function(){
        if(iname == true){
          this.$refs['image'+parseInt( i )][0].src = reader.result;
        }
    this.form.other_image[i] = reader.result
  }.bind(this), false);
  reader.readAsDataURL( this.files[i] );
    }
  }
},
// vue file upload
onFileMultipleChange(e) {
let uploadedFiles = e.target.files;
  for( var i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.length; i++ ){
     this.files.push( uploadedFiles[i] );
}
this.getImagePreviews();
},

   async resetform() {
    window.location.reload();
  },
  async saveImage() {
  //form data post code
  },
   },
  }
 </script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question from the code you provided. When is `ImagePreview()` being called? What events are triggered from the second input? Please add all necessary code to reproduce the issue and consider creating a [playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/).

Comment: Please share your full component code

Comment: i'm assuming my v-bind:ref have some issue

Comment: i have updated the code , i have added input 2 field. i have same fields like that one. even if i change the value of ither field than this , the previews are disappears as well . none of the form fields are able to hold the preview. @MoritzRingler

Comment: Still impossible to tell from the code you posted what is causing the issue. My guess is that you are triggering a submit and it causes a reload of the page, despite the `@submit.prevent`. But, again, impossible to know from what you posted. I can show you how to load the previews without using refs, but that wouldn't help if it is a reload issue.

Comment: What else you need to show tell me I'll post that. And if there's any other options to preview the images please tell me I'll try to apply that. Also i tried to stop reload the page by hotReload : false.. didn't work . I stucked so badly. Please help @MoritzRingler

Comment: Please post your whole component. Remove other inputs not related to the issue, but only if it does not break anything.

Comment: i have uploaded the whole vue file code. can you please check now ?!  @MoritzRingler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I put your component into a [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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), everything seems to work. Please confirm that the error does not occur there.

You can adjust the playground until it reproduces the error and then add it to your question. Until we can actually see the error, there is nothing we can do for you.

---

As you requested, here is how you could build the image preview without using `ref`. Instead of putting the data URLs into the img tags through `$refs`, the data URLs are written to a regular data array and then used directly in the v-for. I have also moved it into its own component, so it does not clutter the other already huge component:

```js
const ImagePreviewsComponent = {
  props: ['images'],
  template: `
  <div class="bg-light mt-4 w-50 row">
    <div class="file-listing col-6" v-for="(dataUrl, key) in imagePreviews" :key="key">
      <img :src="dataUrl" class="w-100"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      imagePreviews: [],
    };
  },
  watch: {
    images: {
      async handler(){
        this.imagePreviews = []
        const promises = [...this.images].map(image => this.loadImagePreview(image))
        this.imagePreviews = await Promise.all(promises)
      },
      immediate: true,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async loadImagePreview(image){
      const reader = new FileReader()
      const promise = new Promise(resolve => reader.onload = resolve)
      reader.readAsDataURL(image)
      await promise
      return reader.result
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {'image-previews': ImagePreviewsComponent},
  data() {
    return {
      images: [],
    };
  },
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="app" class="m-2">

  <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-xl-4">
    <div class="custom-file">
      <input
        multiple="true"
        type="file"
        @change="e => images = e.target.files ?? e.dataTransfer.files"
      />
    </div>
    
    <image-previews :images="images"></image-previews>

  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.10/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Here it is in the [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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) from before.

Comment: i have come to conclusion that my current method will not work with other js. it's conflicting . can you please suggest me the other easy way to do the same !? thanks for all the help so far..

Comment: Have a look at the updated answer. But since your code seems to work in a playground, I am not sure if changing this part fixes the error. Have you tested if the component gets reset from the outside? You can simple put a log statement in the mounted hook, and see if it is called when you lose your data. Again, if you manage to get me a reproducible example, I can tell you why it is not working pretty quickly.

Comment: i was tring to apply this code by merging the code with mine. but failed try. can you guide me with where i need to place the code block of const ImagePreviewsComponent  ?? i have placed the methods and watch code but unable to place this one.. sorry for bothering you so much as i have not mch knowledge of vueJs

Comment: Why are you trying to merge it? Just create a new component

Comment: I have added it to the playground, have a look at the link at the end of the answer